# Send notification to pin owner

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to send a notification (ActionMailer) to the owner of a pin when some user has voted for the pin. This is working, however I did not manage to print the name of the voter in the email notification. Any help is welcome!

I have the following in my pin controller:

```
def like
  @pin.liked_by current_user
  redirect_to :back, notice: 'Je hebt dit recept nu toegevoegd aan jouw bewaarde recepten.'
  ModelMailer.new_like_notification(@pin).deliver
  end
```

[EDIT] have the following mailer:

```
def new_like_notification(pin)
@pin = pin
@user = pin.user
mail to: pin.user.email, subject: "#{@pin.user.name}, jouw recept #{@pin.description} wordt lekker gevonden door anderen.", bcc: "oliviervanhees@gmail.com"
end
```

[EDIT] And I have created this part in my view to show the voter of the pin:

```
<% @pin.votes_for.voters.each do |p| %>
<li><%= p.name %></li>
<% end %>
```

So the last part gives the following error NoMethodError in Pins#like

Answer (score 1):

Define `@user` as `pin.user` in your mailer or refer to it as `@pin.user` in your view.

Comment: I don't understand. Is this way I get the owner of the pin, not the person who liked the pin???

Comment: I want to show the liker of the pin to the owner by putting it in the subject line or content of the email notification